# I want to put a color on my T-shirt. What should I add to the Node Editor?

Tags: node-editor

I am studying Blender with T-shirt from game.

I want to put a color on my T-shirt.

What should I add to the Node Editor?

.blender file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hPpF22-GI4c_R0fbcAFM8VG6ut4KzCJP
[image]

Comment: Please include your texture in your .blend too, else we will see the t-shirt as pink, as missing textures are pink. You can do this by going to File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend

Comment: Thanks your advice. I modified the link to include the texture.

Comment: you should follow tutorials on how to create a material from scratch, I think it's the best way to learn

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you recommend one related course? Do you have a link address?

Comment: You can just click on the grey area next to Color1 in the MixColor/Diffuse node (the second one from the top) and choose the color you want